# Simple array in array in C++

Tags: c++

I'm collecting a set of colors in separate arrays. After then i want to store all of them in an array that contains these arrays, so i can iterate through all colors at once. i want to do it like this:

```
 const float COLOR_GREEN[3] = {0.00f, 1.00f, 0.01f};
 const float COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE[3] = {0.99f, 0.00f, 0.99f};
 const float COLOR_CYAN[3] = {0.00f, 1.00f, 0.99f};
 const float COLOR_BLUE[3] = {0.00f, 0.00f, 0.99f};
 const float COLOR_YELLOW[3] = {1.00f, 1.00f, 0.01f};
 const float COLOR_BROWN[3] = {0.82f, 0.40f, 0.12f};
 const float COLOR_ORANGE[3] = {1.00f, 0.55f, 0.001f};
 const float COLOR_PINK[3] = {1.00f, 0.20f,  0.701f};
 const float COLOR_LIGHT_GREY[3] = {0.67f, 0.67f, 0.671f};
 const float COLOR_DARK_GREY[3] = {0.33f, 0.33f, 0.333f};
 const float COLOR_DARK_GREEN[3] = {0.18f, 0.54f, 0.341f};
 const float COLOR_DARK_RED[3] = {0.20f, 0.00f, 0.01f};
 const float COLOR_DARK_PURPLE[3] = {0.50f, 0.00f, 0.51f};
 const float COLOR_DIRTY_GOLD[3] = {0.50f, 0.51f, 0.00f};
 const float COLOR_BLUEISH_GREEN[3] = {0.00f, 0.50f, 0.51f};


static const float COLOR_LIST[15][3] = {{COLOR_GREEN},
                                           {COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE},
                                           {COLOR_CYAN},
                                           {COLOR_BLUE},
                                           {COLOR_YELLOW},
                                           {COLOR_BROWN},
                                           {COLOR_ORANGE},
                                           {COLOR_PINK},
                                           {COLOR_LIGHT_GREY},
                                           {COLOR_DARK_GREY},
                                           {COLOR_DARK_GREEN},
                                           {COLOR_DARK_RED},
                                           {COLOR_DARK_PURPLE},
                                           {COLOR_DIRTY_GOLD},
                                           {COLOR_BLUEISH_GREEN}
                                        };
                                        };
```

But it's not possible like this because i can't convert const float* to const float.
at the end i want to iterate through this array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
  std::cout << COLOR_LIST[i][0] << ", " << COLOR_LIST[i][1] << "," << COLOR_LIST[i][2] << std::endl;
}
```

where COLOR_LIST[0][0] = 0.00f, COLOR_LIST[0][1] = 1.00f, COLOR_LIST[0][2] = 0.01f, etc...

what am i doing wrong here?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this line to:
`const float* COLOR_LIST[15]`

Answer (score 1):

Make it to point to array..

```
static const float* COLOR_LIST[15] = {COLOR_GREEN,    
    COLOR_LIGHT_PURPLE,                                         
    COLOR_CYAN,                                          
    COLOR_BLUE,                                          
    COLOR_YELLOW,                                        
    COLOR_BROWN,                                         
    COLOR_ORANGE,                                       
    COLOR_PINK,                                        
    COLOR_LIGHT_GREY,                                   
    COLOR_DARK_GREY,                                    
    COLOR_DARK_GREEN,                                  
    COLOR_DARK_RED,                                   
    COLOR_DARK_PURPLE,                                 
    COLOR_DIRTY_GOLD,                                    
    COLOR_BLUEISH_GREEN                                   
    };
```